# How to move all files of a certain extension to another folder, but keep the folder structure?

Tags: powershell, file, directory, move

I'm organizing my game collection, but many games have the CD image inside folders. I created a new partition to hold just the cd images, and wanted to move them quickly rather than having to go into each folder.

Example like this now:

```
(D:)
 (FullGameName)
   (Gamename.files...)
   (CD)
     (game.iso)
```

How I want it to be:

```
(D:)
 (FullGameName)
   (Gamename)
     (Gamename.files...)

(E:)
 (FullGameName)
   (CD)
     (game.iso)
```

I tried a few things in PowerShell, but the most I got was a folder full of CD image files (without the folder tree). I'm using windows 10

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and the problem you're having. Also, this is only possible to do programmatically if `FullGameName` will always be at a specific depth i.e. from your example, we know that `FullGameName` is the parent of `CD`. Will that always be the case?

Answer (score 0):

This script retrieves all subfolders in the source folder using `Get-ChildItem` with the `-Directory` parameter.

It then iterates through each game folder and extracts the full game name and game name from the folder structure.

Your destination folder path will be constructed using `Join-Path` based on the provided directory structure. If the destination folder doesn't exist, it is created using `New-Item`.

Next, the script searches for .iso files within each game folder using `Get-ChildItem` with the `-Filter` and -File`parameters. If a CD image file is found, it is moved to the destination folder using`Move-Item`.

```
$sourceFolderPath = "D:\Source\Game\Folders"
$destinationFolderPath = "E:\Destination\CD"

# Get all subfolders in the source folder
$gameFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolderPath -Directory

# Loop through each game folder
foreach ($gameFolder in $gameFolders) {
    $fullGameName = $gameFolder.Name
    $gameName = $gameFolder.GetDirectories().Name

    # Construct the destination folder path
    $destinationFolder = Join-Path -Path $destinationFolderPath -ChildPath $fullGameName
    $destinationFolder = Join-Path -Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath "CD"

    # Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationFolder)) {
        New-Item -Path $destinationFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    # Get the CD image file
    $cdImage = Get-ChildItem -Path $gameFolder.FullName -Filter "*.iso" -File

    # Move the CD image file to the destination folder
    if ($cdImage) {
        Move-Item -Path $cdImage.FullName -Destination $destinationFolder
    }
}
```

I tested this locally with some Playstation ISO's I downloaded and was able to successfully achieve what I believe your goal is based on the description of the problem. Hope this helps!